# Why does DbContext instantiate repositories?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

In the following code, DbContext instantiates repositories in derived class. I believe it does this somehow by reflection in its constructor. 
These are my questions :

1. Why and for which purpose it does it?
2. Is instantiating properties in self or derived classes a best practice?
3. If it is a best practice which design pattern is it related to and what is the name of this behavior?

This is the only code in my project, I just add entityframework reference to a console application project :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new DataContext();
        if(context.Products != null)
            Console.WriteLine("why repositories are not null?!");
    }
}

public class Product
{
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Jenish, thank you for your edit.

Comment: In your first sentence you say repository and under "2." you say properties. My best guess is, that you are confused on what a repository is. `Products` is a collection of entities, not a repository.

Comment: I believe that DbSet Properties in a DbContext derived class is an example of UnitOfWork and Repository design pattern. Products is a property and is also a repositry. DataContext is a class and is also a unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext is a class that is internal to the Entity Framework assembly so you cannot modify it within your code. Therefore, by creating DbSet properties in your derived class, Entity Framework maps the properties of type T to database table columns. Most of the internal Entity Framework magic happens within the DbSet class.

Comment: In my project there is not any database and therefore there is not any mapping. this is not about entityframework. if you create a class, are properties null by default or they are instantiated? this is not ordinary that properties are not null by themselves.

Comment: @JafarElahi it totally depends on the implementation of the class. if you give the properties default values in the constructor, then the properties will not be null. Ideally you do not want properties to be null ever. Null is generally evil.

Comment: Exactly, you said another edition of my question. what is this behavior called and is it a best practice?